# Cannot seem to use TFS API, how to correctly import items from the SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to write some simple code to connect to a `TfsTeamProjectCollection`, however, I continue to get the message :

> "type or namespace name
>   'WorkItemStore'/'WorkItemCollection'/'TfsTeamProjectCollection'/'Project'
>   could not be found."

I have tried to find the TFS SDK, and how to install it, but I can't seem to figure this out - I seem to be blind as this is definitely well documented somewhere. I believe I need to install some of [these](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4188) items, and then add them as references to my project? Could this be correct ? Which of these items do I need ?

Thanks very much, apologies for the silly question - I have recently given up coffee!

Comment: What is the code that is giving you that error?

Comment: The code giving me the error is just simple declaration of variables. I don't know how/what the correct items to import are, or where to download them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try referencing the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

It is installed with Team Explorer.

Comment: Perfect! Couldn't find that information anywhere else, believe it or not! Thank you :)